# Dirichlet problem on ellipse in $R^3$

Tags: partial-differential-equations

[image]

Need some help with part (ii), finding the solution $u$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppos $u$ and $v$ are two functions satisfying the stated conditions.  Then

$\nabla^2(u - v) = \nabla^2 u - \nabla^2 v = -1 - (-1) = 0 \tag 1$

in $R$, and

$p \in \partial R \Longrightarrow u(p) - v(p) = 0 - 0 = 0; \tag 2$

thus $u - v$ is a harmonic function on $R$ and hence attains both its maximum and minimum on $\partial R$ in accord with the [maximum princple for harmonic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_principle); but these are each $0$, so

$0 \le u - v \le 0 \tag 3$

on $R$, whence

$u = v; \tag 4$

thus is uniqueness had.

Now consider a quadratic function of the form

$u = \dfrac{\rho x^2}{2a^2} + \dfrac{\rho y^2}{2b^2} + \dfrac{\rho z^2}{2c^2} - \dfrac{\rho}{2}, \; \rho = -\left (\dfrac{1}{a^2} + \dfrac{1}{b^2} + \dfrac{1}{c^2} \right )^{-1}  \tag 5$

it is easy to see that

$\nabla^2 u = \rho \left ( \dfrac{1}{a^2} + \dfrac{1}{b^2} + \dfrac{1}{c^2}\right ) = -1 \tag 6$

in $R$; also, for

$(x, y, z) \in \partial R, \tag 7$

we have

$\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} + \dfrac{z^2}{c^2} = 1, \tag 8$

whence

$u(x, y, z) = \dfrac{\rho x^2}{2a^2} + \dfrac{\rho y^2}{2b^2} + \dfrac{\rho z^2}{2c^2} - \dfrac{\rho}{2}$
$= \dfrac{\rho}{2} \left (\dfrac{x^2}{a^2} + \dfrac{y^2}{b^2} + \dfrac{z^2}{c^2} \right) -\dfrac{\rho}{2} = \dfrac{\rho}{2} \cdot 1 - \dfrac{\rho}{2} = 0; \tag 9$

we thus see that the quadratic function $u$ as defined in (5) meets the specified requirements

$\nabla^2 u(x, y, z) = -1, \; (x, y, z) \in R \tag{10}$

and

$u(x, y, z) = 0, \; (x, y, z) \in \partial R. \tag{11}$

Finally, the integral

$\displaystyle \int \int_{\partial R} \nabla u \cdot d\mathbf S, \tag{12}$

where $d \mathbf S$ is he outward pointing area element on $\partial R$, may be evaluated *via* the divergence theorem as follows:

$\displaystyle \int \int_{\partial R} \nabla u \cdot d\mathbf S = \int \int \int_R \nabla \cdot \nabla u \; dV, \tag{13}$

where $dV$ is the volume element in $R$; proceeding in light of (10),

$\displaystyle \int \int \int_R \nabla \cdot \nabla u \; dV = \int \int \int_R \nabla^2 u \; dV$
$= \displaystyle \int \int \int_R (-1) \; dV = -\int \int \int_R dV = -\dfrac{4}{3} \pi abc, \tag{14}$

where $4/3 \pi abc$ is the [volume of $R$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipsoid).